# How to assign variables to a value in text file and check if it satisfies a given condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file in.txt

```
name="XYZ_PP_0" number="0x12" bytesize="4" info="0x0000001A"
name="GK_LMP_2_0" number="0xA5" bytesize="8" info="0x00000000bbae321f"
name="MP_LKO_1_0" number="0x356" bytesize="4" info="0x00000234"
```

I need to check whether it satisfies the condition that is check if **info value** of number "0x12" + 0x00000004 = info value of `number="0x356"`.

If it matches print the resulted value matches with given info value of `number="0x356"`.

else print not matching.

How can i do this?

this is current attempt:

```
import re
pattern = r'(number=\"\w+\").*(info=\"\w+\")'

with open("in.txt", "rb") as fin:
     for line in fin:
          for match_number, match_info in re.findall(pattern, line):
```

but this will simply extract the number and info value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break it into steps.

1. Look up how to read in a text file, line by line. You'll end up with a list of lines of this file.
2. Figure out how to extract the value from the "number" field. A simple regular expression would serve you well here I think.
3. [Optional] Cast  this value to the correct data type for your problem.
4. Do the comparison you're interested in.

You can easily google the syntax for all of these I think.

Edit: posted before there was any code in the original post. I'm not entirely sure what the question is anymore. Do you need help debugging?

Edit 2: Taking another stab at this since I think you're asking for RegEx syntax.

Change your RegEx pattern to have parentheses around the information you want to extract. A RegEx match for such a pattern will allow you to assign the values inside this parentheses to Python variables.

See this partial example.

```py
import re
pattern = r'number=(\"\w+\").*info=(\"\w+\")'
s = 'name="XYZ_PP_0" number="0x12" bytesize="4" info="0x0000001A"'
m = re.search(pattern, s)

if m:
  number, info = m.groups()
  print("number is ", number)
  print("info is", info)
# number is  "0x12"
# info is "0x0000001A"
```

Comment: The code i gave will extract all the number value and info value from text file. What i need is to only search number="0x12" and store it's info value to a a variable. and then same for number="0x356" and store it's info value to a variable. so that i can compare them.

Comment: so what i need is how to extract the info value of number="0x12" and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Isn't that what your code already does?

`for match_number, match_info in re.findall(pattern, line)`

You extracted the matches here

Comment: yeah but that will extract all the number and info pattern in file

Comment: what i need is search for number="0x12" and store it's info value to a variable. same goes for number="0x356"

Comment: Well sure, but you can just check the match info, right?

Comment: yes it will give all info values.

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know what you think